# compact set in metric space and in normed vector space?

Tags: general-topology

I have this simple question of topology:

Do compact sets in metric spaces and in normed vector spaces are always closed and bounded ??

(vector space of infinite dimensions)

thanks ......

Comment: That's true in any dimension. Compact $\Rightarrow$ closed is true for all Hausdorff topological space.

Comment: John Ma 13 how about bounded ??

Comment: Try to use the following open cover $B_1(0), B_2(0)\cdots $,